# html2image not working

Tags: ubuntu, 32-bit

This is displaying when I try to run html2image command for html to image conversion:

**"html2image: error while loading shared libraries: libasound.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"**

Comment: fixed that by "sudo apt-get install libasound2" 

now getting "html2image: error while loading shared libraries: libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: read the instructions text file

Comment: It's not an answer to your Q but I've better experience with html2image if you use the latest Chromium. Especially as an M1/ARM/MacOS processor, because it's significantly faster than default Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with ubuntu, getting these when tried html to image:

**AUDIT: Fri Oct 22 16:15:42 2010: 28352: client 1 connected from local host ( uid=1000 gid=1000 pid=29515 )
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".
current dir: /var/www/pressflow/html2image/libxpcom.so
Couldn't start XPCOM.ubuntu@ip-10-243-110-162:/var/www/pressflow/html2image$ AUDIT: Fri Oct 22 16:15:42 2010: 28352: client 1 disconnected
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi, removing from list!
[config/dbus] couldn't register object path**

Answer (score 0):

The correct command to resolve this in Ubuntu is:

`sudo apt-get install libasound2`

You will also get the best milage from having the latest version of Chromium.